# Java + Primefaces : Use "sortBy" attribute with a nested map

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm developing a web app with Primefaces, but have a nested Object to represent the data I'm getting from database.

To be concrete : I'm doing a request on many columns, returning many rows, so I'm stocking this result in a `List<HashMap<String, Object>>` (each **"String key"** is the name of a column with the associated **"Object value"**). In a normal way, I'm supposed to have a `List<MyObject>` to save my data, where **MyObject** has as much attributes as columns my request has. But I can't do it, because I'm constructing a page rendering the result of my request, and the columns can be dynamically managed in an admin space (so you can add or remove columns in admin space by simply checking/unchecking boxes and validating your changes. I'm forced to do a `List<HashMap<String, Object>>` so.)

Primefaces **p:column** in **p:dataTable** has a "**sortBy**" attribute, but Primefaces seems only support the sorting on **Object** attributes (that's why I was saying "In a normal way, I'm supposed to have a `List<MyObject>` to save my data").

Actually, I'm looking for something that can replace the `#{myBean.list.attribute}` in "**sortBy**". (an EL like `#{myBean.list[?]['key']}` or something like this)
In other words, I'm trying to find a way to force Primeface to do a sort on each value of each Map in the List, value linked by the key I'm passing.

For exemple, my request returns me a list of songs, every song is characterized by his singer, type, date, country.

So I'll have for example this List :

```
Map1(<Singer, SamTsui>
<Type, Pop>
<Date, 2010>
<Country, US>)

Map2(<Singer, Jo>
<Type, Blues>
<Date, 1988>
<Country, US>)

Map3(<Singer, DaftPunk>
<Type, Electro>
<Date, 2013>
<Country, FR>)

Map4(<Singer, Shinee>
<Type, Kpop>
<Date, 2009>
<Country, JP>)
```

How can I do a sort on the Singer of each song ? Or the date ?
Is there a way to do this or I'm forced to have a `List<MyObject>` to use the "**sortBy**" feature on **p:column** ?

Thanks a lot,

PS : having the same question for "**filterBy**", but I think if we find a solution, the way to solve this problem will be similar.

PS2 : I don't think we need code, it's just a general question, because the question can be asked for everyone trying to display a `List<HashMap<?, ?>>` or a nested Object with Primefaces, and wanting to add filters/sorts on this list.